# Z-index is not bringing the text on front

Tags: css

Currently, I'm working with on http://rccsite.wpengine.com/rcc-remediate/. The page has a slider that has text "Building across Auckland" and a "Read more" button.

I've spent more than an hour already trying to figure out why the nested div that has a class "slide-text" is not bringing the text and the link on the front. Currently the image with class "graphic-square" is on the front that has z-index of 1 it is needed to be on top on the image but not on the pieces of text of the slider.

I tried to add:

```
.slide-text {
z-index: 200;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
right: 100px;
max-width: 190px;
}
```

Already made the z-index on 200 its not getting the desired output.

However, I successfully made the div tag on front, on the right that says "Building better".

**Is there anyway to achieve this?**

**Why is the pager is working when z-index is applied but not on the slide text**? I think, I'm missing something here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is ok in your site http://screen.w3.ua/Feb15/7310440.jpg

Comment: make sure youre setting the stacking context value of the elements youre expecting to be behind.

Comment: @kumar, I'm sorry I can't get your suggestion. It seems there's nothing changed there.

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull, thanks for the idea. However I can't think of any structure that I can make the square on top of the slider images but not on the slide text part. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out! I have to split the the graphics-square image in two parts. Removed the middle part of the image, allowing the text to be on front. And it worked.

Thanks for the idea Matt.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is just because of the below code:

```
<img src="http://rccsite.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-child-jed/images/graphics-square.png" class="graphics-square">


.graphics-square {
  display: block; /* Make it display: none; */
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;  /* Make it z-index: 0; */
}
```

Just hide the .graphics-square class and things will work  OR you can set it's z-index: 0;

Try it at your end and let us know.

Comment: I can't hide the graphics-square since I need it to be on the top of the image but not on the .slide-text. You can see that there the white square with opacity on top of the slide image(s)